# Removing image dimensions from `the_content`

Tags: images, filters, the-content

I'm looking to remove image dimensions from `the_post_thumbnail`, as well as `the_content`. I've found the following code, but there's a slight issue:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

The issue I have with this code is that it'll end up removing the width / height attributes from any element, this could be a problem for `iframe` or `object` elements.

What's the best way to only remove these attributes for `img` elements, and nothing else.

Comment: Hmmm... actually I could just use the CSS `max-width` trick, that'll supersede the element attributes.

Comment: Why would you need to remove the image dimensions? Perhaps if you explain the reasons in your question, somebody can give you better answers.

Comment: Just check for the `<img>...</img>` tag and conditionally remove attributes only in this cases - take a look at the first comment at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/stuntbox/4557917). I haven't tested this though, but you'll get the point from that.